# Ask the user for its name using raw_input

Tags: python-3.x, raw-input

How do I write a program that uses `raw_input` to prompt a user for their name and then welcomes him.

For example that asks: `Enter your name`, and then the program continues welcoming the user with `Hello NAME_OF_THE_USER`

Comment: Homework?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Next time, please make an effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the easiest problem ever. This is my solution (since you tagged your post for Python 3):

```
name = input('Enter your name: ')
print("Welcome", name)
```

For Python 2, just change `input` to `raw_input`, and remove the parenthesis of the `print` function.